# Include deprecated code with Sencha Cmd

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

My Sencha Touch app relies in much of the framework's deprecated code

This is an example of a deprecated piece of code in the framework files

```
//<deprecated product=touch since=2.0>            
if (Ext.isObject(configObj) && ...) {            
   ...
}
//</deprecated>
```

My problem is, that when I use sencha cmd, specifically `sencha app build testing` all the deprecated code is removed in the resulting `app.js` file, and due to that I of course have many bugs.

Btw, I can't remove/upgrade the code that needs the deprecated sections (for reasons beyond the scope of this question).

How can I include deprecated code with `sencha app build` (or similar) command?

Thanks

PS: I'm using Sencha Touch 2.2.1 (however I think this applies to ExtJs also) and Sencha Cmd 3.1 if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
sencha config --prop build.options.minVersion=0 then app build testing
```

This instructs to include code deprecated in all versions >= 0, which means... all.

This can be also configured in a config file, for example:

```
build.options.minVersion=0
```

in `sencha.cfg` or another of the config files.

Hope this helps to someone